# Refresh apenas 1 vez

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou realizando a criação de um site e preciso de uma força.

O problema é o seguinte, preciso que ao entrar no site o mesmo de um `refresh`, exatamente ao entrar nele

Tentei o código:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```

Entretanto ele fica num `looping` infinito de `refresh` e eu necessito que isso ocorra somente uma vez.

Comment: Faz uma função `Javascript` para isto, procura por **location.reload()**

Comment: axo que precisara de um contador para parar o refresh

Comment: Que problema você quer resolver fazendo isso? Vi pouquíssimos casos onde isso era realmente necessário.

Comment: Realmente! Postei uma sugestão que pode atender mas isso tem cara de gambiarra :)...

Comment: Na real pessoal é gambiarra mesmo, este é meu erro principal:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333002/erro-na-galeria-de-imagens

Comment: Então não faça isso, é uma péssima ideia ter que recarregar a página apenas para consertar algo que já está com problema. É melhor concentrar-se na outra pergunta para resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma função e aplicar uma condição.

```
    window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#carregar';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma, irá continuar num looping infinito de refresh

Comment: É verdade, vou atualizar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Cara acredito que não seja uma boa solução fazer um refresh logo após acessar o site.

Mas você pode usar o comando:

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: Vai continuar no looping. Ele irá entrar na página, irá recarregar, e ficará assim.

Answer (score 0):

Se não houver outra maneira de corrigir seu problema... ou enquanto não ache uma solução ....

**javascript** passo a passo

1. pegue o url da página
2. Verifique se há algum parametro na url
3. Se não houver faça redirecionar para a própria pagina acrescentando um parâmetro.
4. No redirecionamento com parâmetro não vai executar o script

   ```
   var url=window.location.href;
   var parametrosDaUrl = url.split("?")[1];

   if (!parametrosDaUrl){

      window.location = "parametrosDaUrl.html?stop=yes";

   }
   ```