# Erro na Galeria de imagens

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit: https://github.com/amrodr/galeria_projeto

Pessoal estou tendo um pequeno problema, quando eu dou upload dos meus arquivos para o servidor as imagens ficam assim, entretanto quando esta local ele funciona normalmente.

O erro só é corrigido caso eu de refresh na pagina, caso não dê refresh as imagens ficam assim um em cima da outra!

[image: Erro relatado]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara inclui tb o CSS e o JS da sua galeria, e se possível passe o link ai do projeto pra gente poder inspecionar. E qual é a versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: Não, eles se movem de forma responsiva, este erro só apresenta caso eu não atualize a pagina, se atualizar eles vão para o espaço adequado

Comment: https://github.com/amrodr/galeria_projeto aqui esta o repositorio para verificar o projeto

Comment: Localizei a linha mas não encontrei o erro neste codigo, ele só da erro quando tá no servidor

Comment: Fiz isso mas não me permitiou utilizar o menu de marcas

Comment: Então o codigo fica assim ?    var $grid; $(window).on("load", function(){
 if(document.getElementById("menu") ||  document.getElementById("gallery")){
           $grid = $(".grid").isotope({

Comment: Continua travando o menu e eu não sei por qual motivo

Comment: Alterei as linhas de codigo do Main.js, localmente tudo esta ok, quando coloco no servidor continua com o mesmo erro de uma imagem sobrepor a outra, vou adicionar a imagem na pergunta !

Comment: Ao colocar esse Script no HTML ele para de ler meu arquivo KKKK e da erro no menu novamente

Comment: Agora deu certo graças a você, o resultado saiu como o esperado, fiz limpeza de cache e historico no navegador acessei o site, as imagens aparecem uma em cima da outra e após carregarem completamente elas são realocadas cada uma em seu devido lugar, você esta de parabéns, sou muito grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O componente que você está usando está calculando de forma errada as dimensões das áreas das imagens porque elas ainda não foram carregadas. Em suma, o componente trabalha de forma assíncrona com o carregamento das imagens.

Para resolver isso, chame as opções do componente apenas quando as imagens forem carregadas, usando `$(window).on("load"...`, desta forma:

```
var $grid = $(".grid").isotope(); // declara a variável atribuída ao componente
$(window).on("load", function(){
   if(document.getElementById("menu") || document.getElementById("gallery")){
         $grid.isotope({
           itemSelector: ".all",
           percentPosition: true,
           masonry: {
             columnWidth: ".all"
           }
         })
   };
});
```

Você declara a variável `$grid` antes do `$(window).on("load"...` para que ela tenha escopo fora da função, pois você irá precisar dela em outra parte do código, como neste evento de clique:

```
$('.filters li').click(function(){
  $('.filters li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var data = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: data
  })
});
```

> Outra coisa que notei é que você tem um `$(document).ready(function()
>   {` principal e outros dentro, além de uns `$( function() {`. Isso é
>   redundância de código, basta apenas o `$(document).ready(function() {`
>   principal.

Comment: Sou bem leigo ainda estou iniciando nesse mundo, então fazer as coisas funcionarem ja é de grande valor kkk, preciso melhorar bastante o código mas com o tempo vou me aprimorando, muito obrigado por me ajudar e por me mostrar os erros que garanto não serão mais cometidos !

Answer (score 1):

A culpa tem sido de um dos javascripts e no caso o `isotope.pkgd.min.css`.

Você pode usar [imagesLoaded](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded) para resolver isso.
Adicione este trecho no seu arquivo `mais.js`, lá pela linha `61` está bom.

```
 // layout Isotope after each image loads
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
      $grid.isotope('layout');
    });
```

Explico, a primeira vez que sua página é carregada, as imagens ainda estão sendo carregadas então a biblioteca não tem referência de tamanhos para carregar. Incluindo esse trecho fará que o layout seja recalculado para cada imagem sendo carregada.
Por isso, ao dar F5, as imagens que já estão em cache são carregadas na DOM antes da execução do script, então fica tudo ok.

Obs: Alternativamente pode também inserir este javascript em seu html, mas o resultado do primeiro método é mais fluído e bonito.

```
    <script>
        $(window).load(function(){ $('.grid').isotope() });

    </script>
```

Veja como ficou em
http://jsfiddle.net/guiljs/cmxa2Lf0/